# Custom chapter title for talk transcripts

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I have been asked to prepare a transcript for a series of talks. For that reason, similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183498/custom-chapter-template), I am trying to create a custom chapter template like this:
[image].

Moreover, I need that the `\tableofcontents` page format should be:
[image].

How can I do that efficiently? I have just copied the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183523/38244) of the question, but now I am clueless. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need a command, that takes at least 8 arguments (day, title, speaker, institute ...). Maybe the most comfortable way would be to use a kay-val approach, so youdon't have to remember the order. Should the toc really say *Talk <number>` ot give the corresponding title?

Comment: @Johannes_B I just forgot to write Talk name. It should be like **Talk #**, then Talk Heading in the next line.