# How to use a frame around a text in latex

Tags: graphics

i want [image]to make the same frame in the picture or something like that , if anyone can help me with the code then i'll be so thankful!

Comment: Welcome! You can use e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183523/194703) as a starting point.

Comment: This resembles the `Glenn` chapter style of [`fncychap`](//ctan.org/pkg/fncychap). See the [`fncychap` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/fncychap).

Comment: Welcome to ,TeX SX! This is very close to the `Glenn` chapter style from `fncychap`.

Comment: thank you very much everyone !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by the comment.